# Initialize pytest test objects in the test, not in the `parametrized`/collection phase

Tags: python, pytest

I have a number of pytest tests that I run like

```py
import pytest

from mymodule import *


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "arg",
    [
        fun1(),
        fun2(),
    ] 
    + [
        fun3(n) for n in range(10)
    ]
    + [
        fun4(n, model)
        for n in range(3, 7)
        for model in ["explicit", "implicit"]
    ],
)
def test_foobar(arg):
    # ...
    pass
```

Some `fun*` take long to initialize, but I don't know which since the initialization happens in the pytest *collection* phase. I'd rather move initialization into the function itself *without adding much boilerplate code*.

How would I achieve that? Note that different `fun` methods have different signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Pass "thunks" (zero-argument functions that wrap the calls to other functions) as arguments instead of the results of the functions, then call the thunks inside the test. Functions that already take zero arguments can be passed as is without an additional thunk.

```
from functools import partial

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "arg",
    [
        fun1,
        fun2,
    ]
    + [partial(fun3, n) for n in range(10)]
    + [partial(fun4, n, model) for n in range(3, 7) for model in ["explicit", "implicit"]],
)
def test_foobar(arg):
    arg = [f() for f in arg]
    # lots of testing
    pass
```

We use, for example, `partial(fun3, n)` instead of `lambda: fun3(n)` to ensure that the correct *value* of `n` is passed to `fun3` when the `partial` object is called.

Comment: One could also store tuples like `((fun3, (n,)) for n in range(10)`, and pass `fun` and `args` to `test_foobar`, right?

Comment: You could, but then you'd either have to pass `(fun1, ())` into `test_foobar`, or figure out which elements of `arg` are callable and which are tuples that contain callables. Using a thunk keeps `test_foobar` itself simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar approach to chepner. The differences are

1. I use function and args
2. I use `pytest.param` which allows generating a test ID

```py
import pytest

from mymodule import func1, func2, func3, func4


def make_test_data():
    yield pytest.param(func1, tuple(), id="func1")
    yield pytest.param(func2, tuple(), id="func2")
    for n in range(10):
        yield pytest.param(func3, (n,), id=f"func3 with {n=}")
    for model in ["explicit", "implicit"]:
        for n in range(3, 7):
            yield pytest.param(func4, (n, model), id=f"func4 {n=}, {model=}")


@pytest.mark.parametrize("func,args", make_test_data())
def test_foobar(func, args):
    actual = func(*args)
    assert actual  # Perform test
```

Notice the test IDs in the output:

```
test_me.py::test_foobar[func1] PASSED                               [  5%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func2] PASSED                               [ 10%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=0] PASSED                      [ 15%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=1] PASSED                      [ 20%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=2] PASSED                      [ 25%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=3] PASSED                      [ 30%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=4] PASSED                      [ 35%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=5] PASSED                      [ 40%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=6] PASSED                      [ 45%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=7] PASSED                      [ 50%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=8] PASSED                      [ 55%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func3 with n=9] PASSED                      [ 60%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=3, model='explicit'] PASSED         [ 65%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=4, model='explicit'] PASSED         [ 70%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=5, model='explicit'] PASSED         [ 75%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=6, model='explicit'] PASSED         [ 80%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=3, model='implicit'] PASSED         [ 85%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=4, model='implicit'] PASSED         [ 90%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=5, model='implicit'] PASSED         [ 95%]
test_me.py::test_foobar[func4 n=6, model='implicit'] PASSED         [100%]
```